# PHP: Illegal string offset

Tags: php

I know there already are questions like this, but It didn't help me.

I get the follow error on my site:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'networkConnections' in
>   /var/www/bitmsg/templates/header.php on line 25 {

The line is
    
`<?= $bmstatus["networkConnections"] ?> p2p nodes`

if I `print_r` $`bmstatus`, then I get:

```
{
    "numberOfBroadcastsProcessed": 2308,
    "networkStatus": "connectedAndReceivingIncomingConnections",
    "softwareName": "PyBitmessage",
    "softwareVersion": "0.4.1",
    "networkConnections": 52,
    "numberOfMessagesProcessed": 22888,
    "numberOfPubkeysProcessed": 8115
}
```

How to I fetch the information from this array?

I've tried both `$bmstatus['networkConnections']` and `$bmstatus->networkConnections`
but both is returning that error?

Comment: user echo "<pre>"; var_dump($bmstatus) and show results

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$bmstatus` contains a JSON string. You have to decode it first to be able to extract the required information out of it. For this purpose, you can use the built-in function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) (with the second parameter set as `TRUE` to get an associative array, instead of an object):

```
$json = json_decode($bmstatus, true);
echo $json['networkConnections'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, doh!, I knew that, I must be tired :) +1

Comment: @G33K1E: Glad to have been of help :)

Answer (score 9):

It's a json string. You need to decode your json response using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter `true` to get as an associative array.

```
$bmstatusArray = json_decode($bmstatus,true);
echo $bmstatusArray["networkConnections"];
```