# PHP: How to fix illegal string offset?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch data by using `json_decode` function.

**Here are the `print_r` results:**

```
Array
(
    [ticker] => Array
        (
            [base] => BTC
            [target] => USD
            [price] => 3796.85831297
            [volume] => 173261.82951203
            [change] => 6.29130608
        )

    [timestamp] => 1545745501
    [success] => 1
    [error] => 
)
```

When I want to call the price value with `foreach`, it shows the value however with this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'price'

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
       $price = $value['price'];
       echo '<br>' . $price;
}
```

**Here are the `var_dump` results:**

```
array(4) {
  ["ticker"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["base"]=>
    string(3) "BTC"
    ["target"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    ["price"]=>
    string(13) "3796.85831297"
    ["volume"]=>
    string(15) "173261.82951203"
    ["change"]=>
    string(10) "6.29130608"
  }
  ["timestamp"]=>
  int(1545745501)
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Some people have identified my question as a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266820/php-illegal-string-offset). However `echo $json['price'];` shows nothing!

Comment: You can't iterate over JSON, because it's a string (unless you want to iterate over it character by character). Once you decode it, it ceases to be JSON and turns into a datastructure of primitive types (bool, null, float, int, string) and aggregates (stdClass, array) thereof. That said, please extract a [mcve]. Not only does that add to the value of your question, it also helps you to find the error yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is **OK** but you've to make sure that your `$value` is an array and it contains the `price` key otherwise you'll get

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'price'

To fix that you can use `is_array()` on **$value** , `isset()` and `!empty()` on **$value['price']**

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value) && isset($value['price']) && !empty($value['price'])){
        $price = $value['price'];
        echo '<br>' . $price;
      }
}
```

Comment: isset with not empty is one another good approach.

Comment: @devpro Yes sir agreed, **Edited**

Answer (score 3):

You can used [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$price = array_column($json, 'price');
echo $price[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure $value is an array and contains the key.

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
       if(is_array($value) && isset($value['price']))
       {
           $price = $value['price'];
           echo '<br>' . $price;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
   $price = $value['ticker']['price'];
   echo '<br>' . $price;
}
```

Your `price` key is nested one level deep inside `ticker`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried this way. But in this way, both it doesn't show the price and it shows two errors:
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'ticker'`
`Warning: Illegal string offset 'price'`

Comment: Can you show us how you're using `json_decode()`, please?

Comment: only first value has price, he is getting error after first value. )